# Identification of $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^4+X+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As mentioned in the title I would like to show that we can identify $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^4+X+1)$ with the set $K$ of polynomials: $p_0+p_1 a+p_2a^2+p_3 a^3$ in a variable $a$ that we assume satisfies $a^4+a+1=0$.

If you have any ideas than can help me with that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general construction:

1. Let $\mathbb F$ be any field and $p(X)\in \mathbb F[X]$. The quotient ring $R=\mathbb F[X]/(p(x))$ consists of elements of the form $q(X)+I$, where $I=(p(X))$.
2. Now, you can use the division algorithm for polynomials and obtain that $q(X)=p(X)\cdot t(X)+r(X)$ for a unique polynomial $r(X)$ of degree smaller than the degree of $p(X)$. It thus follows that every element in $R$ is equivalent to some element of the form $r(X)+I$, where $\deg(r)<\deg(p)$.
3. A straightforward verification shows that no two such elements are equivalent, and thus the set $R$ can be identified with the set of polynomials $r(X)\in \mathbb F[X]$ of degree smaller than the degree of $p(X)$. The ring operations are given by addition and multiplication on the representatives, and then taken modulo $I$.
4. A direct verification shows that the element $\alpha = X+p(X)$ in $R$ satisfies the equation $p(x)=0$.

Comment: I improved the formatting, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, two questions; In my case $q(a)=p_0+p_1a+p_2a^2+p_3a^3$, correct? Is there are straightforward argument such that $K\without\{0\}$ is a cyclic group and therefore $K$ a finite field with $2^4$ elements?